# PERSISTED Computed Column vs. Regular Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a high performance DB (on SQL Server 2012). One of my views had a virtual column represented by an inline scalar valued UDF computing custom hash from the previous column value. I moved this calculation from the view into one of the underlying tables to improve the performance. I added a new computed column to the table and persisted the data. Then, created index on this column and referenced it back in the corresponding view (basically migrating the logic from the view into the table).

Now I am wondering why wouldn't I just add a regular VARCHAR(32) column to the table instead of the computed PERSISTED column? I could create a DEFAULT on this column with the above mentioned UDF for all new inserts and recalculate the historical records.

Is there any advantage of the indexed computed column with PERSISTED data vs. regular NC indexed column?

Thx.

Comment: What is a "regular NC index column"?

Comment: In this case a new column of VARCHAR(32) datatype with Non-Clustered Index. I guess it should show as a result in SELECT * FROM sys.columns
WHERE is_computed <> 1.... am I understanding your question right?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I assume he means a pretty normal column, with a nonclustered index on it. He then writes some calculation result into this column, for speeding up queries.

Comment: @Milan: you can't use `UDF` for a default in SQL Server

Comment: @Quassnoi . . . According to the documentation, you can (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: the OP mentioned he wants to use other columns in the UDF, can you do that in a `DEFAULT`?

Comment: @Quassnoi: ....actually I think you may be correct, since the value passed into the UDF is not know at the time of INSERT... I have to try this (someone correct me if I am wrong....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computed column will keep your field up to date if the field data it is based on is changed.  Adding just a default will update the field on insert if no value is provided for the field.

If you know that your data is not going to change (which i think you are implying but did not specify in your question), then they are functionally the same for you.  The computed column would probably be preferred though to prevent accidental update of the field with an incorrect value (bypassing the default).  Also it is clear to any other developers what the field is to be used for.

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to a "normal" column with a default value or insert trigger.  The one potential issue is that unlike a computed column anyone with insert/update access could (potentially accidentally) change the value of the column.

Performance is going to be the same either way. In essence that is what the db is doing behind the scenes with a persisted computed column.  As a developer a column that is persisted computed is clearer in the intent than a default value.  Default value implies it is one of many possible values not the only possible value.

Be sure to declare the UDF With SchemaBinding.  This will allow SQL Server to determine if the function is deterministic and flag it as so.  That can improve query plan optimization in some cases.

Comment: Triggers will have more overhead than defaults/computed columns as the presence of a trigger requires the `inserted`/`deleted` tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance difference. However, in terms of database design it is more elegant when you have your pre-calculated column in the persisted view.

Comment: ...ok, but wouldn't that impact the performance considering the frequent R/W against the underlying tables ?

Comment: @Milan - If there is frequent R/W against the underlying tables why would that make any difference? The only extra W activity would be from keeping the column in synch and you need that anyway.

Comment: @Milan No, because the engine is clever enough to update only the rows you changed. Well, the only other difference is that the persisted view is stored in a separate table. So in a way, you could store it on a separate disk, for example - that way you could improve performance a little bit. (For this case, I'm talking of a persisted VIEW, not a persisted calculated table column).

Comment: Wouldn't the concurrent indexing (on the view as well as on the underlying tables) created unnecessary overhead?